# Is there a way to delete a line in Visual Studio without cutting it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to delete a line just like hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> without anything selected, but without saving the line to the copy stack.  Is this possible?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

`Edit.LineDelete` is the name of the command.  By default it's bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, but you can give it whatever you like in Tools | Options | Keyboard.

**Edit**: Corrected default shortcut info.

Comment: LineDelete!  Why did they have to name it backwards!  It looks like in VS2010 it is bound by default to `Ctrl + Shift + L`, though.

Comment: @musicfreak, when I first sought this command, I typed "Line.Delete" and looked for what was there (this command is omitted when you search in that fashion).  The *terrible* UI only allows me to see 4 results at a time (for me, contrary to that screen shot in the other answer.) which makes it a real pain.

Comment: @musicfreak, I did search for "line" and "delete".  But with so many results returned from those searches, it makes it very difficult to locate.

Comment: @JChristian: Fair enough. :) They definitely could've made that interface a lot more user-friendly.

Comment: @nathan_hc, that actually performs a **cut**, which pollutes the clipboard.  (Try it yourself and paste after using CTRL-L)

Comment: Alas this doesn't work as expected when word wrap is enabled. Please vote for the bug report at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/138259/cut-command-should-delete-logical-line.html

Comment: Glad to learn this, never needed this feature so much until today, now I wonder how I ever lived without it (and polluted my clipboard) for all those years...

Answer (score 54):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will delete the line and not copy to the clipboard.

Comment: Yeah but it's less than useful.  I'd be mapping Delete + Shift or Ctrl to do the same rather then having to press three keys.

Comment: I personally have this set as Ctrl + E to make it easier to use.

Comment: Ctrl + E? I'd be more inclined to keep the xcv and make it shift + x just thinking about it.

Comment: @griegs: Shift + X? Then how do you make a capital X?

Comment: LOL, Oh yeah, oops.  Never liked captial x anyway!

Comment: it's Ctrl + D for me, a habit I picked up from Elipse

Answer (score 31):

I mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Global) to `Edit.LineDelete`. Otherwise, the shortcut key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, which is awkward. Go to `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard` as shown below.

[image: Tools | Options | Keyboard]

Answer (score 29):

**Correction in my answer**

**Ubuntu 16** & 
**Visual studio Version: 1.30.1**

To cut line
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>

To delete line <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>

Comment: Shift + Del worked for me in VS 2015 with ReSharper

Comment: Visual Studio Code 1.39.2 under Windows has the same shortcut `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `k`

Comment: `Shift`+`del` works in VS 2017.

Answer (score 19):

CTRL + L (Visual Studio 2019 Windows)

Comment: OH, thank you for pointing out SHIFT isn't necessary

Comment: SHIFT is absolutely necessary if you want to be able to remove the line without cutting. CTRL + L does the same as CTRL + X or SHIFT + DEL. To be able to remove a line without copying it you need to use CTRL + SHIFT + L.

Answer (score 13):

Its <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> on mac by default.

But it can be modified according to user needs from the settings (`Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts`) -> search for `Delete Line` key value.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

`Cmd` + `Shift` + `K`  deletes the line and the cursor will then be at the same position as it was on the deleted line but on the line that gets sucked up. Or if that line is shorter than at the end of that line. Great!

`Cmd` + `L`  on the Mac on the other hand selects the current line and puts the cursor at the start of the next line. So when overwriting your cursor will insert before the whitespace indentation of the next line. Most of the time not what you want.

Answer (score 9):

## Valid Answer By 2023 for VS Code (with image)

All the above answers regarding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> are now deprecated.

The correct default behavior is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
(<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> if you're a MAC user).

**To change this default behavior:**

1- Go to `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` (OR click Ctr+K Ctrl+S)

[image]

---

2- Type in the search bar `delete line`

[image]

Here you will find the corresponding behavior. You can change it just by double-clicking on it and pressing any desired combination of keys on your keyboard (pay attention of conflicting shortcuts).

Answer (score 7):

By default, if you are using the C# default profile, you can delete a line using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

You can customize this using Tools->Customize.  Select "Keyboard".  Look for the command **Edit.LineDelete** to assign it to whichever keyboard shortcut you like.
[Source](https://superuser.com/a/194006)

---

If you got here looking for an answer for Visual Studio **Code** the default shortcut is:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> for Windows

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> for MacOS

However, you can change on `File > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts`

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+delete",
    "command": "editor.action.deleteLines",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/1161116)

Answer (score 5):

none of the above answers worked for me. to delete a line in visual studio code use :**shift+del**

Answer (score 2):

On Visual Studio 2019 for Mac, it's CTRL + K to cut the whole line by default.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers were helpful but didn't seem to work for me.

So I found the solution --> for Visual Studio 2017 (and certainly 2019):

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > on the right pane select **Edit.LineEdit**.

Below there is a ComboBox *Use new shortcut in:* with **Global** written --> Change it to **Text Editor**.

On the right there is a Text input *Press shortcut keys:*, so use the shortcut of your choice.

Then click on Assign PushButton on the right (otherwise it won't be applied).

Finally > OK.

You can now open a .CPP file and use your shortcut to remove a line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a url for the keyboard short cut reference for windows:
https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

For windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are specific to Visual Studio, which is what was requested by OP, however if anyone is looking for a more generalized way to do this for most Windows programs, you can also **Triple-Click to select any block of text, then just press the Delete key.**  This works for any Windows text editors or TextBoxes, including password boxes, search boxes, browser web address boxes, etc.  For text editors such as Visual Studio, a block of text is typically one line of code.  Obviously you can do other things too, such as triple-click to select a line of code, then Ctrl-X, Ctrl-V to cut/paste, etc, or just triple-click and type over it to replace a line.