# Visual Studio delete all characters of a line

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'd like to achive the following: _ is the cursor

```
public void Foo() {
    List<Bar> bars = new_
}
```

Press Shortcut

```
public void Foo() {
    _
}
```

And not delete the whole line like this:

```
public void Foo() {
}
```

I found this Question, but that is not what i want. 
[Is there a way to delete a line in Visual Studio without cutting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731968/is-there-a-way-to-delete-a-line-in-visual-studio-without-cutting-it)

Is there a shortcut to achieve this behavior?

Comment: One shortcut if possible

Comment: Ctrl+L will delete the line. I realise it's not what you want - but it's that or Shift+Home, Delete. You could always write an extension for VS to do what you are looking for.